# Eventos onmouseover e onmouseout demorando a trocar imagens

Tags: javascript, html, eventos-do-mouse

Estou com um problema ao utilizar os eventos `onmouseover` e `onmouseout` que ao passar o mouse ele faz a troca das imagens mas ele é muito lento demora muito, existe outra forma para fazer isso seguindo o exemplo abaixo.

```html
<img src="imagens/img01/time011pb.png" id="img2" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/img01/time011.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/img01/time011pb.png'"/>
```

Comment: Bruno, tens mais imagens que precisem dessa funcionalidade ou é só uma caso único?

Comment: Você quer trocar as imagens ou só colocá-la em escala de cinza? Se for só escala de cinza, não precisa ser outra imagem

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou com `css`? Vou dar um exemplo.

```css
span.switch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url('http://thumb10.shutterstock.com/photos/thumb_large/546601/113982157.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px
}
span.switch:hover {
  background-position: 0px -37px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <span class="switch"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Dessa maneira, existe apenas uma única imagem que é carregada uma única vez. Quando passamos o mouse por cima da imagem, o CSS apenas muda a posição do background.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja o caso de fazer um preload da imagem secundária antes de mostrar a primária. As imagens abaixo tem 900 e 700 KB, imagens maiores podem ser [encontradas aqui](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Photos_taken_with_Leica).

```js
function preloadImagem( url )
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function () {
        var container = document.getElementById('img2');
        container.style.display = 'block';
    };
}
preloadImagem( 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Blomster.jpg?v=3' );
```

```html
<img 
    src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Blomstereng-NAN.jpg?v=3" 
    id="img2" 
    onmouseover="this.src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Blomster.jpg?v=3'" 
    onmouseout="this.src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Blomstereng-NAN.jpg?v=3'"
    width="300"
    hidden />
```

<sub>*Referência: [JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3646036/1287812)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Usa o img:hover, define um background-image pro img, e depois outra background-image para o img:hover, eu pelo menos faria assim.

Se ajudar, http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html